# Convert std::array<std::array<T,N>> into std::vector<T> in modern C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector

I have a buch of triangles represented by a vector of 3d vectors (`std::vector<Vector3>`) and indices, represented in the following way

```
using int3 = std::array<int, 3>;
std::vector<int3> indices;
```

I need to convert the `indices` into a `std::vector<size_t>` format to interact with a library.

I know how to do this using raw loops, but I would like to here about how to do it using algorithms. I tried something like

```
std::vector<size_t> indices_converted;
std::transform(std::begin(indices), std::end(indices), std::back_inserter(indices_converted), [](const auto &v) {
});
```

but is not enough, since I can't insert three values at once into the `indices_converted` vector.

So, what are your ideas?

Comment: Using pseudo language, explain how you would like to go from three ints to a single size_t. Or post your "raw loops" example.

Comment: You need to have an explicit loop to add all the elements one by one. The good news is that since the size is known you can [reserve storage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) so the vector doesn't have to be resized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One-liner using latest version of [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library:

```cxx
#include <array>
#include <vector>

#include <range/v3/view/join.hpp>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>

// ...

std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> v = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
const auto result = ranges::views::join(v) | ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

[<kbd>On godbolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/C5W2U4)

Comment: Please note that this ranges library is standardized for c++20

Comment: This is a very interesting approach! How does it work? does the join function goes from one range to the next jumping from the end of one range to the begin of the next one?

Comment: I've expected that `join` works lazily and that performance would be on par with manual loop that inserts everything into a vector. Quick benchmark shows that my snippet above works even better than manual loop with initial call to `reserve`. Amazing.

Comment: @Grisha do you know if its possible to replace the `to<std::vector>` with `to<std::array>`?

Comment: @M.Mac Seems that `ranges::to` does not yet support `std::array`. Approximation with `std::copy`: `const auto joined_view = ranges::views::join(v);
 std::array<int, 9> a;
 std::copy(begin(joined_view), begin(end), a.begin());`

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the range-based for loop or the standard algorithm `std::for_each`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    using int3 = std::array<int, 3>;
    std::vector<int3> indices = 
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    std::vector<size_t> indices_converted;
    indices_converted.reserve( 3 * indices.size() );

    for ( const auto &item : indices )
    {
        indices_converted.insert( std::end( indices_converted ), std::begin( item ), std::end( item ) );
    }

    for ( const auto &item : indices_converted ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    using int3 = std::array<int, 3>;
    std::vector<int3> indices = 
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    std::vector<size_t> indices_converted;
    indices_converted.reserve( 3 * indices.size() );

    std::for_each( std::begin( indices ), std::end( indices ),
                   [&indices_converted]( const auto &item )
                   {
                    indices_converted.insert( std::end( indices_converted ), std::begin( item ), std::end( item ) );        
                   } );

    for ( const auto &item : indices_converted ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

In the both cases the output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```